# Macbook Pro 2018 Ventura Not Detecting Additional Monitors From KVM Switch

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, ventura

I'm on MacBook Pro 2018 Ventura 13.5. I have three monitors connected to a KVM switch, two through HDMI, and one through DP. The middle monitor is connected through DP, the monitors on the left and right are HDMI. For some reason my Mac only detects the middle monitor, and the left monitor mirrors the middle one. The monitor on the right never outputs anything. I've tried doing the "Detect Monitors" option. I've made sure the OS is up-to-date. I've disconnected/reconnected/restarted. I'm just not familiar enough with Macs to know what steps to take next or how to proceed. Any help is appreciated. [image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if you take the KVM switch out of the picture and plug all 3 into the Mac?

Comment: @SteveChambers Same thing. The middle display is the only display that's "Detected" and the left one mirrors the middle.

Comment: Which model MBP?  How are you connecting these displays to the Mac?  What resolutions are they set to?

Comment: @Allan I'm not really sure what you mean by which model. It's the 15 inch 2016. The Model Identifier says MacBookPro15,1. I'm connecting them through a Falwedi dock station which I recognize could be the issue, https://www.amazon.com/Falwedi-Display-Ethernet-Adapter-Compatible/dp/B086RQ3XPF. I've also tried a j5Create dock station, but none of the monitors worked with that one. The one monitor that the mac recognizes is set to 1080p.

Comment: The model is important be cause the number of external displays supported varies. Can you add the info in comments with an [edit]?

Comment: @Allan I added a screenshot of the Hardware Overview. I also just realized it is the 2018 model...so made those updates, too

Comment: The info about the docks is also key here because it's not mentioned in the question and is relevant as it sits between your Mac and the display.  What connector on the dock(s) are you using to go the monitors?   Also, the first step in troubleshooting things is to get down to basics.  Remove the dock(s) and connect the monitors directly to the Mac.  Does the problem still exitst?